# For a DataGridView, how do I get the values from each row?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am wondering what is the best way to go iterate through all the rows in a datagridview and get the values from the cells.
Here is what I am thinking of doing, but I don't really like it because if I rearrange the columns then the code will also have to be changed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
{
   string Value0 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];
   string Value1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1];
   string Value2 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` to iterate over the `DataGridViewRow`s within the `DataGridView` and use the column names to retrieve the values from the `Cells`:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    string col1 = dr.Cells["Col1"].Value.ToString();
    string col2 = dr.Cells["Col2"].Value.ToString();
    string col3 = dr.Cells["Col3"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for except I had to make a minor change from "dr.Cells["Col1"].ToString()" to "dr.Cells["Col1"].Value.ToString()"

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I modified my answer to add `Value` for anyone else who finds this answer.

Comment: Ninja'd, I was about to add you need to have the Value to get the correct data from the Cell.

Comment: I am not getting DataGridViewRow class. I am working in c# language. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what if we also want to get column name and we dont know column name ?

Comment: @HirenHPatel using System.Windows.Forms is required.

Answer (score 1):

NullException may occur to avoid this error you can modify the above code as following

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    //variables with looop through
    string col1 = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["col1"].Value);
    string col2 = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["col2"].Value);
    string col3 = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["col3"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. I had to explicitly type the iterators instead of using `var`.

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
{
   foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
   {
       //Do Stuff
   }
}
```