# DatGridView table to a new Table in Access 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have a DataGridView that receives 3 columns (Bound) from a Table in an Access database.
There are 5 other columns that are Unbound and after making changes.

Here are is the datagridview

```
ID (Bound from xsd file)
First name (Bound from xsd file)
Last Name (Bound from xsd file)
Active (Bound from xsd file)
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
```

I want to save the following to another table called **WeeklySchedule** (or update the table with values from the datagrid)[would also be nice to load the data from WeeklySchedule if it's there]

```
ID
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
```

So when I update the table by selecting the checkbox (Monday->Friday) and click on a button

I want to update the table ***WeeklySchedule*** with those values for the ID in the same row.

Example

row 1 and 2 have the following data

```
 POID  FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME  ACTIVETODAY  MONDAY  TUESDAY WEDNESDAY THURSDAY FRIDAY
  1     JOHN       SMITH      X            X       _        _        X        X
  2     JASON      SMITH      _            X       X        _        X        X
```

In the first table, I want to save the "ActiveToday" state (if it changed)

In the second table, I want to update/insert the schedule M-F

If my approach is wrong or I am overthinking the solution. Please let me know

Comment: Great. What have you tried so far to do this?

Comment: I don't know where to start. I used Google and attempted a few suggestions but it didn't bear any fruit

Comment: So if there's an `ID` of 1234, every time there is an entry in that DGV, you want the system to update the values in Monday, Tues..etc? I feel like your question is not explicitly telling us what you want to do.

Comment: I updated the question. Let me know if there is anything unclear

Comment: @OverMind is my question more clear?

Comment: [See this for looping through a DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581265/for-a-datagridview-how-do-i-get-the-values-from-each-row).. I think your 'ActiveToday' field shouldn't be a field in your table unless you want to update it every single day. It can be a `CASE` or an `IIF()` statement instead, but I guess I'm not sure how you're going to use it, exactly.

Comment: how do I push the data back to a database?